# Removing and Adding a namespace prefix character through ANT deployment

Tags: apex, ant

1. I want to retrive a metadata from a org when we will create the package. I can able to retrive but after retrival in few places of the component like formulas the namespace prefix is added 'Test__' becasue of this I can't able to deploy to the sandbox or the developer org. If I need to deploy without any error I have to remove this namespace prefix manually. Is there any way while retriving the metadata we can able to remove the namespace prefix in standard salesforce retrival?

2. Once the development is done in the Sandbox we want move all the metadata to org where we will create a package.Before moving do i need to manually update the namespace prefix eg. IN workflow field update formulas.  Is this correct ? if yes can we able to automate this process.